# Information regarding visa appeal process

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, south-africa

I applied for work visa for South Africa but it got rejected as one document was missing.So I applied for appeal in month of August and today I got call from Embassy to submit my passport to the visa office.

I am totally unaware of appeal process.If any one help me out why the embassy need passport.

Comment: It may well be approved Now and they may have called for your passport for the Visa :)

Comment: @Hanky Panky. Thanks a lot. but I have heard it takes a long time for appeal process and I got call within 2 weeks.So i am bit confused.As nothing was disclosed from embassy side even if I asked.They just said come and submit the passport..

Comment: if you sent the missing document with your appeal they may just have reopened the original application and added it in the dossier. Not all bureaucrats are hopeless :)

Comment: I would guess it's an approval. Otherwise why would they need your passport if they have not made any decision on your appeal. Cheer up

Comment: What you have is 'post submission anxiety', rather than a real issue. Please come back to us with a scan of your refusal letter if you are actually denied a visa. Closing the question until then.